# Visual Studio Code の拡大縮小ができません。

Tags: vscode

エディタに長い記述をしたので縮小して全体が見えるようにしたいと思います。
メニューの「表示」→「外観」→「ズームアウト」を選択したり、
ショートカットの「Crtl」+「-」を押してみたのですが、

【ユーザー設定に書き込めません。ユーザー設定を開いて、ファイル内のエラー/警告を修正してからもう一度お試しください】

とエラーが出ます。エラー画面の「設定を開く」をクリックするとjsonの画面が出てきます。
そのjsonのファイルに

"editor.mouseWheelZoom": true, // マウスホイール文字サイズ変更：Ctrl + ホイール

と記述してやるとCtrlを押しながらマウスホイールで拡大、縮小は出来るようになりました。マウスホイールで拡大、縮小が出来ると作業中にいきなり画面が大きくなったり小さくなり面倒ですよね。4

またよくわからずに
"workbench.action.zoomIn": "true",
"workbench.action.zoomOut": "true",

なども記述してみたのですが、何の変化もありませんでした。

メニューやショートカットの「Ctrl」+「-」では縮小できません。

前質問で教えていただいた
「ファイル」→「ユーザー設定」→「キーボードショートカット」のファイルは以下の添付画像のようになっています。
https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11237812526

鉛筆印を押すと編集画面に変わり
「任意のキーの組み合わせを押し、Enterキーを押します」という画面が出てくるので「Ctrl」 + 「-」を押すと「2つの既存のコマンドがこのキーバインドを使用しています。」というようなメッセージが出てきます。
既に存在しているのに、拡大、縮小が効かない状態のようです。

これ以上、どうすれば良いのかわかりません。
わかる方いらっしゃいました教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下記のエラーは設定ファイルの[記述が間違っている](https://qiita.com/miriwo/items/4aab8e6ee4cd64faa48a)時に表示されます。

`【ユーザー設定に書き込めません。ユーザー設定を開いて、ファイル内のエラー/警告を修正してからもう一度お試しください】`

設定ファイルを俯瞰すると`"editor.minimap.enabled":false"`の末尾に`,`が付いていないようです。
省略の都合で省いたのかもしれませんが、`settings.json`の記述に間違いがないか見直してみてください。

またキーバインドも`Zoom In`と`Zoom Out`に同一の`-`キーがバインドされている点が気になります。
まずは改修した点を元に戻して基本に立ち返ってから設定を見直すと、案外うまく行くかもしれません。

なお、キーバインドをカスタマイズしていない私の環境で「Crtl」+「-」を試したところ、正常にズームアウトしました。